# Robolectric throws Resources$NotFoundException when trying to access resource in raw folder

Tags: android, android-resources, robolectric

When I try to access a raw resource I receive an `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060000` error.

The resource is a .bks certificate, used for server validation. It is stored on the `res/raw` folder.

The most awkward thing is that when I copied the certificate (and the validation architecture) to a fresh project (that I built just to test this), it worked!

I'm using nenick's [custom runner](https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/example/myapplication/CustomRobolectricRunner.java), so Robolectric can correctly find the folders for manifest, res and assets. When I go to the intermediates/res/debug folder all the resources are there. I don't have flavours in the project (The project used to have, I removed them. Maybe this is the problem?)

I'm using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2`. `buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'`.
I have a lot of dependencies on the project :(

Also, I'm using `testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2'` and `testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0-rc2'`
The stacktrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060000
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getResName(ShadowResources.java:346)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.openRawResource(ShadowResources.java:385)
    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ssl.CertificateHelper.loadKeyStoreFromRaw(CertificateHelper.java:145)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX.createSSLSocketFactory(XXX.java:432)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX.<init>(XXX.java:92)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX.initiate(XXX.java:73)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:60)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:131)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:431)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:224)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:168)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

java.lang.RuntimeException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060000
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:228)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:168)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060000
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getResName(ShadowResources.java:346)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.openRawResource(ShadowResources.java:385)
    at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.CertificateHelper.loadKeyStoreFromRaw(CertificateHelper.java:145)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX.createSSLSocketFactory(XXX.java:432)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX.<init>(TrafficManagerImpl.java:92)
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX.initiate(XXX.java:73)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:60)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:131)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:431)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:224)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:168)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    ... 1 more
```

Sorry for the "xxx" on the package/class names, but I don't own the code.

**Edit 1 to add the code**

The code that is getting executed at the `onCreate` of the application is:

`InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(keystoreId);`

The variable `keystoreId` is a `R.raw.keystore`.

Does anyone knows what could be causing this?

**Edit 2 to provid more info**

An extra info: I have a different application ID on the build.gradle of the module and on the AndroidManifest. Even when I changed the project to make them be the same, things didn't work and the bug still existed :(

**Edit 3: Android studio update**

With the last android studio update, the test started to be able to find the resources! Except for the ones in the raw folder :(
I'm solving it by putting a big ugly `if` in my code, but as this is not a solution for my question, I'll not close it...

Comment: "fresh project (that I built just to test this), it worked!" Hard to help when all work except the code we don't have. Would be great if you find the difference.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, as the code is not "mine", I cannot disclose it :( I posted here to see if someone had the same problem. To make things worse, the project is big, so the bug can be anywhere. Nonetheless, I think pretty awkward that it occurs. I'll debug a little more an see if I notice something new...

Comment: It occurs on my code, too. I use Robolectrict 3.0. Hmm...

Comment: Is there any fix or workaround for this issues. I'm getting the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I hope Nenick will correct this answer if it is wrong. But you don't need his custom runner with your setup. You can use `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` instead.

Comment: Custom runner isn't necessary. But helpful if you are a Mac user. An exception is if you have a library module because robolectric rc2 has a path issue there but is fixed with snapshot version.

Comment: I've got the same problem and I tried `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`, but now I'm getting this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: No 'constants' field in @Config annotation!
 at org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner.getAppManifest(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.java:30)`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I am on a Mac. How could I remove the custom runner to see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: Hi @sak , in your case, I think the solution is to add the annotation `@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)` in your Test class.

Comment: @nenick Needs to have is own StackOverflow tag for solving Robolectric issues!

Comment: @nenick I did both. I have @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class and also RobolectricGradleTestRunner. Still getting this error

 java.lang.RuntimeException
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Comment: @Sowmya best is to create a sample project at github and post it. Without we must ask all details first to guess was what is wrong. Also look for the open/closed issues to this topic at robolectric https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Resources%24NotFoundException+is%3Aclosed